# Facebook Javascript SDK security

Tags: security, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm in the process of using the facebook javascript sdk to provide user login functionality for a website.

What I'd like to do is simply take the logged in user's unique facebook id and then put/fetch data to/from a mysql database using the id to determine what data is available to said user.

However I don't really feel like this is very secure. Whilst I'm not storing anything sensitive like credit-card details etc, I'd obviously prefer it to be as secure as practically possible.

My fear is that with javascript being what is it, someone could fake the facebook id and just pull whatever they wanted.

I'm aware that the php sdk would provide a solid solution to this problem, but i like the javascript one mainly because it's easy to use and I have the basis of it set up (I admit it, I'm lazy).

So, my questions are:

1. Would this set up be as insecure as I feel it might be?
2. Is there anything I can do to improve the security of such a system, other than switching to the php sdk?

Thanks!

Comment: Would you be saving data from their facebook or data related to your site? and are you doing this over SSL?

Comment: I daresay using javascript for anything remotely related to validation is insecure - remember, javascript executes client side, so for all intensive purposes a malicious user is capable of manipulating any input you receive, and can selectively prevent javascript-based validation you have from running.

Comment: The only thing I'd be saving is the user's uid, used to identify the correct table from which to add/pull data, and age. Not done using SSL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Facebook Ids are pretty hard to make up (at most a user will only know their own). Depending on what you store in the database (which will not be anything that the user cannot get on their own, unless you ask for extended permissions)

If you are worried about a user trying to get information from the database, add an access token or signed request to each row and us that and facebook id to get data. That will greatly increase security.

**EDIT**

There are few occasions where you get a signed request from a user:

```
* A signed_request is passed to Apps on Facebook.com when they are loaded into the Facebook environment
* A signed_request is passed to any app that has registered an Deauthorized Callback in the Developer App whenever a given user removes the app using the App Dashboard
* A signed_request is passed to apps that use the Registration Plugin whenever a user successfully registers with their app
```

Signed requests will contain a user id only if the use has accepted permissions though, and are not passed again if the user enters the application, and accepts permissions (meaning that the signed request would not contain the ID). Because of this saving an access token may be a better idea. Here is more on the [signed request](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/)

Also the signed request is in the url (param = "signed_request"). I always parse it through c# but I am sure you can at least get one through javascript

Comment: Having done a bit of reading, ideally what I'd like is an encrypted string from facebook which contains the users uid, which I could then go and read using my fb app's secret key.

It appears that a signed request would fit this description perfectly, however I am unaware of how I could call one of these on request? Ideally using the javascript API. If anyone knows if this is possible I'd love to know.

The fb access token is something that I can find on request, but the uid isn't encrypted, being just a string in the middle of it.

Comment: The first statement that faceboook ID's are only known to the user is incorrect.  There are plenty of sites on the net you can use to lookup  the ID, so they are not secure. You do have to use the signed request.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty easy to spoof the origin using curl. I'd imagine Facebook has another mecanism in place to make this possible. If you inspect their code, it appears that they generate an iframe and pass requests through. If I had to guess, they have setup the requests to only be made from the Facebook domain, and ensure that the iframe can only be embedded in a page that has a white listed domain.